# Selecionar td com base no texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma tabela onde quero selecionar as `td's` que contenham determinado texto. Já tentei opções como:

```js
console.log($("#minhaTabela").find("td[value='A']"));
console.log($("#minhaTabela").find("td[text='A']"));
console.log($("#minhaTabela").find("td[innerText='A']"));
console.log($("#minhaTabela").find("td[context='A']"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="minhatabela">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Todos as opções acima não retornam nada. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, o id da tabela estava errado no código (em camelCase quando no html está em caixa baixa). O CSS não é capaz de filtrar por conteúdo, o `[]` vale apenas para atributos.

Mas como você está usando isso dentro do jQuery, pode usar o [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```js
console.log($("#minhatabela").find("td:contains('A')"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="minhatabela">
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```